# Not understanding why a type is not being narrowed inside an if-check

Tags: typescript

Trying to figure out why I'm getting the error in question.

```
type Result = {
  loading: true,
} | {
  loading: false,
  data: string | Error,
};

function getResult(): Result {
  return { loading: false, data: new Error("Hello!") }
}

interface ILoadingOrError {
  result: {
    loading: true,
  } | {
    loading: false,
    data: Error,
  }
}

function y(param: ILoadingOrError): void {
  if(param.result.loading) {
    console.log("loading");
  } else {
    console.log(param.result.data.message);
  }
}

function x() {
  const r = getResult();
  if (r.loading === true || r.data instanceof Error) {
    // Type 'Result' is not assignable to type '{ loading: true; } | { loading: false; data: Error; }'.
    // Type '{ loading: false; data: string | Error; }' is not assignable to type '{ loading: true; } | { loading: false; data: Error; }'.
    //   Type '{ loading: false; data: string | Error; }' is not assignable to type '{ loading: false; data: Error; }'.
    //     Types of property 'data' are incompatible.
    //       Type 'string | Error' is not assignable to type 'Error'.
    //         Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Error'.(2322)
    y({result: r});
  }
}

x();
```

Inside the if-condition, it is guaranteed that `r` is either `{loading: true}`  or `{loading: false, data: Error}`.

Is this a narrowing bug, or am I misunderstanding something about how type narrowing is supposed to work?

EDIT: I filed this as an [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/45726) in Typescript. It sounds that even though this should work, making it so would slow down compilation too much.

> Type guards do not propagate type narrowings to parent objects. The narrowing is only applied upon access of the narrowed property which is why the destructing function works, but the reference function does not. Narrowing the parent would involve synthesizing new types which would be expensive. More detail in this comment.

Comment: `y({result: { loading: r.loading, data: r.data }});` works https://tsplay.dev/WPjJJN, but that really shouldn't be necessary. It appears that the type of `r` is not being narrowed, even though the type of `r.data` _is_ being narrowed. Which is definitely strange.